# Is it possible to obtain the commandtext for a stored procedure that includes everything required for EXEC?

Tags: .net, sql

In using `SqlCommand.CommandText` MSDN tells us it returns the name of the SP when calling an SP.  For debugging purposes I would like to be able to extract the SQL as it is run in the DB along with params.  This way I can run `EXEC` and slap on the SQL for debugging in the database or displaying debugging info to other programmers.

Can it be done?

Comment: One thing that makes this difficult is that you'd need to be able to separate string and numerical data since strings need to be delimited. Also how would you handle table-valued parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the first statement.  For my purposes, we do not use table-valued params for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it can, but only if you're not using named parameters.

If you use named SQL parameters, there is *no* SQL that can do exactly what the call does from the debugger.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in your second sentence. You seem to indicate that `exec sp_help @objname = 'foo'` wouldn't work.

Comment: I discovered the hard way they don't do exactly the same thing when the SQL did something in the code the extracted command did not do.